# How to Call java Rest WebService inside a Servlet

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a  java Rest WebService URL `http://localhost:8080/WebServiceEx/rest/hello/dgdg`

When i execute the URL ,the WebService Method Returns a String

My Requirement is to call the above WebService URL inside a Servlet ,Could any one Help?

ServletCode:

```
public Class StoreServlet extends HttpServlet{
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

//Invoke WebService and Get Response String Here


}
```

WebService Code:

```
public class HelloWorldService {
    @Context 
    private ServletContext context;

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

                    return Response.status(200).entity(msg).build();    

                }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Apache CXF JAX-RS client:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html

e.g.

```
BookStore store = JAXRSClientFactory.create("http://bookstore.com", BookStore.class);
// (1) remote GET call to http://bookstore.com/bookstore
Books books = store.getAllBooks();
// (2) no remote call
BookResource subresource = store.getBookSubresource(1);
// {3} remote GET call to http://bookstore.com/bookstore/1
Book b = subresource.getBook();
```

Or, if you use JAX-RS 2.0, it has a [client API](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/spericas/archive/2011/10/14/jax-rs-20-client-api?force=774)

e.g.

```
Client client = ClientFactory.newClient();

String bal = client.target("http://.../atm/balance")
                   .queryParam("card", "111122223333")
                   .queryParam("pin", "9876")
                   .request("text/plain").get(String.class);
```

Or you can do it the "core" way using just plain Java: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to generate a webservice client using jaxws(for this purposes - look up for a tutorial on the internet). Thus you get some Java classes you can use as usually inside your servlet.